# Analysis of android kernel logs after encryption

Tags: android, linux, kernel

I did encryption on my android phone, the encryption was successful (confirmed from logcat).
now the system reboots normally, once it completes boot up, system asked me for disk password to decrypt the userdata.

I entered the disc password and system reboots :O , asking me disk password again. The ideal condition should be device loads the decrypted userdata.

On Checking the last_kmsg logs, it shows kernel panic.  How do I analyse the kernel logs?

below are the kernel panic situation logs,

```
    [   65.969569] WARNING: at kernel/arch/arm/mach-msm/msm-pm.c:837 msm_pm_wait_cpu_shutdown+0xb0/0xd0()

[   65.981686] ---[ end trace 39b994bb8aed4d13 ]---
[   66.303908] init: untracked pid 962 exited
[   66.402400] check_dsi_ctrl_status: rohi:  check_dsi_ctrl_status  IN
[   66.407913] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 000000d4
[   66.418851] pgd = c0004000
[   66.421101] [000000d4] *pgd=00000000
[   66.425927] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[   66.430445] Modules linked in:
[   66.433416] CPU: 0    Tainted: G        W     (3.4.0-gc5da25d-00089-g25d4b28-dirty #2)
[   66.441406] PC is at check_dsi_ctrl_status+0x54/0x1bc
[   66.446349] LR is at check_dsi_ctrl_status+0x14/0x1bc

[   66.451383] pc : [<c03fc68c>]    lr : [<c03fc64c>]    psr: a0000013

[   66.451387] sp : f606ff48  ip : f606fe16  fp : f5422d90

[   66.462914] r10: 00000000  r9 : c03fc638  r8 : f6288010

[   66.468050] r7 : f6289000  r6 : 00000000  r5 : f6288028  r4 : f5422d8c

[   66.474631] r3 : f5b6b2d0  r2 : c03de2a8  r1 : c0c9f75d  r0 : 0000004c

[   66.481072] Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel

[   66.488438] Control: 10c5787d  Table: 34c5c06a  DAC: 00000015

[   66.494091] 

[   66.494093] PC: 0xc03fc60c:

[   66.498416] c60c  e59f1014 01a02003 e5963004 eb156f8b e1a00004 e8bd807c c0c9f63f c0a3ba78

[   66.506499] c62c  c0cdf6f9 c0cc6736 c0c9f660 e92d41f3 e1a04000 e59f1184 e59f0184 eb156f7f

[   66.514658] c64c  e354000c 059f017c 0a00001e e5943044 e5932118 e592506c e3550000 059f0168

[   66.522819] c66c  0a000018 e5152008 e2458018 e3520000 059f0158 0a000013 e5937288 e5976048

[   66.530979] c68c  e59600d4 e3500000 0a000000 eb15aa29 e2877020 e1a00007 eb15aa26 e5943044

[   66.539139] c6ac  e5d3139c e3510000 0a000009 e1a00007 eb15a947 e59600d4 e3500000 0a000000

[   66.547298] c6cc  eb15a943 e59f0108 e59f10f0 eb156f5b ea000039 e5963124 e3530000 0a000001

[   66.555457] c6ec  e1a00006 e12fff33 e59f00e8 e1d032ba e3130004 0a000003 e2800018 e59f10d8

[   66.563619] 

[   66.563622] LR: 0xc03fc5cc:

[   66.567871] c5cc  e3a04000 ea000011 e5d45000 e3a02000 e3550000 03a05007 13a05008 e1a01005

[   66.576031] c5ec  ebfff2f6 e2504000 0afffff4 e59f302c e3550008 e58d4000 e59f2024 e59f0024

[   66.584190] c60c  e59f1014 01a02003 e5963004 eb156f8b e1a00004 e8bd807c c0c9f63f c0a3ba78

[   66.592350] c62c  c0cdf6f9 c0cc6736 c0c9f660 e92d41f3 e1a04000 e59f1184 e59f0184 eb156f7f

[   66.600509] c64c  e354000c 059f017c 0a00001e e5943044 e5932118 e592506c e3550000 059f0168

[   66.608670] c66c  0a000018 e5152008 e2458018 e3520000 059f0158 0a000013 e5937288 e5976048

[   66.616829] c68c  e59600d4 e3500000 0a000000 eb15aa29 e2877020 e1a00007 eb15aa26 e5943044

[   66.624989] c6ac  e5d3139c e3510000 0a000009 e1a00007 eb15a947 e59600d4 e3500000 0a000000

[   66.633151] 

[   66.633153] SP: 0xf606fec8:

[   66.637402] fec8  205b0000 36362020 3230342e 5d303034 00000020 c03fc68c a0000013 ffffffff

[   66.645562] fee8  f606ff34 f6288010 c03fc638 00000000 f5422d90 c0968fd8 0000004c c0c9f75d

[   66.653725] ff08  c03de2a8 f5b6b2d0 f5422d8c f6288028 00000000 f6289000 f6288010 c03fc638

[   66.661881] ff28  00000000 f5422d90 f606fe16 f606ff48 c03fc64c c03fc68c a0000013 ffffffff

[   66.670041] ff48  f5422d8c f5422d8c f6021fc0 f5422d8c ce45c900 ce462c00 ce45ca18 c01af4a8

[   66.678202] ff68  f6021fc0 00000001 00000000 f6021fc0 ce45ca18 f606e000 c16c5319 ce45c900

[   66.686361] ff88  ce45ca18 f6021fd0 00000009 c01af858 00000000 f6059edc f6021fc0 c01af6d4

[   66.694520] ffa8  00000013 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c01b3f34 f6059edc 00000000

[   66.702683] 

[   66.702685] IP: 0xf606fd96:

[   66.706936] fd94  00000017 00000000 c0109c60 00000000 0000000b 000000d4 00000017 00000000

[   66.715093] fdb4  f606ff00 00000017 c0957bf4 f6050f00 c096a9bc 00ac005a f61fd800 f606fdf8

[   66.723253] fdd4  00000000 00000000 c5b41000 0001116b 0000000c f606fe3c c06da00c 00000000

[   66.731412] fdf4  00000080 001d00f3 00ec0097 00b30073 00a6005c 00a900c9 00d10093 006500d8

[   66.739573] fe14  00ad009f 00000046 f61fd800 f61fd800 0001116b 00000046 c03fc68c f606ff00

[   66.747731] fe34  00000017 000000d4 c102bd98 00000007 c102bd28 f5422d90 c01003b4 00016d23

[   66.755892] fe54  00000000 c1055500 00000001 00000001 f606e000 f606fe7c c096ac54 60000093

[   66.764051] fe74  00016d23 c1055488 c0968cc8 c1055488 c0197f44 ffffffff 00000001 0000000f

[   66.772211] fe94  0000004c 00000003 c178528f 00000009 c1055488 60000013 c0198458 00000000

[   66.780371] 

[   66.780373] FP: 0xf5422d10:

[   66.784626] 2d10  f5422d10 f5422d10 c047bb08 c047bb50 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   66.792784] 2d30  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   66.800943] 2d50  f5422d50 f5422d50 f5b6d000 f5435400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   66.809103] 2d70  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c03fc7f4 c4c37a58 00000000 00000000

[   66.817263] 2d90  f5422d90 f5422d90 c03fc638 00000000 00200200 ffffa4be c17a5880 c01b00a4

[   66.825425] 2db0  f5422d8c ffffffff ffffffff 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   66.833583] 2dd0  f5b6b2d0 00001388 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   66.841742] 2df0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 f5401380 c4c4a504 f6121f40 f6121f58

[   66.849903] 

[   66.849905] R1: 0xc0c9f6dd:

[   66.854156] f6dc  725f6266 73696765 5f726574 65696c63 6620746e 656c6961 72202c64 72757465

[   66.862316] f6fc  2064656e 68746977 3d637220 000a6425 253e363c 44203a73 73204953 75746174

[   66.870477] f71c  68632073 206b6365 65746e69 6c617672 0a64253a 3a732500 49534420 72746320

[   66.878633] f73c  7473206c 73757461 726f7720 7571206b 20657565 74696e69 696c6169 0a64657a

[   66.886794] f75c  3e333c00 203a7325 69686f72 6320203a 6b636568 6973645f 7274635f 74735f6c

[   66.894955] f77c  73757461 4e492020 3e333c00 723a7325 3a69686f 49534420 61747320 20737574

[   66.903116] f79c  61746164 746f6e20 61766120 62616c69 000a656c 253e333c 72203a73 3a69686f

[   66.911276] f7bc  6e615020 64206c65 20617461 20746f6e 69617661 6c62616c 3c000a65 73253e33

[   66.919430] f7dc  6f72203a 3a206968 49534420 72746320 726f206c 61747320 5f737574 63656863

[   66.927596] 

[   66.927598] R2: 0xc03de228:

[   66.931847] e228  ebf6d211 eaffffff e1a00000 eaffffff e1a00000 e3500000 e5876110 0a000001

[   66.940005] e248  f57ff04f f57ff06f e5944260 e3a00002 e2841004 ebf6d204 eaffffff e1a00000

[   66.948163] e268  eaffffff e1a00000 e3500000 e5845004 0a000001 f57ff04f f57ff06f f57ff04f

[   66.956328] e288  e8bd80f8 c0c955ca c0a38788 c16cffe8 c0c966f1 00200002 02200202 c17fb6f8

[   66.964484] e2a8  e92d4070 e2504000 1a000004 e59f011c e1a05004 e59f1118 eb15e861 ea000041

[   66.972645] e2c8  e59f0110 e300311a e19030b3 e3130004 0a000003 e2800f42 e59f10fc e59f20f0

[   66.980804] e2e8  ebff265b e2845d11 e1a00004 e3a01001 e2855004 eb001403 e1a00005 eb162a93

[   66.988965] e308  e3a03000 e1a06000 e3a01002 e1a00004 e5843418 ebfffaca e1a00005 e1a01006

[   66.997126] 

[   66.997128] R3: 0xf5b6b250:

[   67.001378] b250  f5419bc0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.009539] b270  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.017698] b290  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c165b998 00000000 f5434200 00000001

[   67.025855] b2b0  c7000000 00000000 c165b9fc 00000000 00000000 f5b6b2d0 00000000 00000000

[   67.034015] b2d0  11161126 00000000 00000000 00000002 00080000 f6288028 00000000 00000000

[   67.042177] b2f0  00000000 00000000 f5b6b000 000007d0 ce480c05 f5b6b304 f5b6b304 c03f88b8

[   67.050336] b310  f602e1cc f602e1cc ffffa536 f602e000 c01b00a4 f5b6b300 ffffffff ffffffff

[   67.058498] b330  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 0000000d 00000000

[   67.066658] 

[   67.066660] R4: 0xf5422d0c:

[   67.070982] 2d0c  ffffffff f5422d10 f5422d10 c047bb08 c047bb50 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.079071] 2d2c  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.087231] 2d4c  00000000 f5422d50 f5422d50 f5b6d000 f5435400 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.095387] 2d6c  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c03fc7f4 c4c37a58 00000000

[   67.103546] 2d8c  00000000 f5422d90 f5422d90 c03fc638 00000000 00200200 ffffa4be c17a5880

[   67.111706] 2dac  c01b00a4 f5422d8c ffffffff ffffffff 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.119867] 2dcc  00000000 f5b6b2d0 00001388 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.128028] 2dec  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 f5401380 c4c4a504 f6121f40

[   67.136188] 

[   67.136190] R5: 0xf6287fa8:

[   67.140514] 7fa8  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa

[   67.148599] 7fc8  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa

[   67.156759] 7fe8  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa f6386e00 f612a3a8

[   67.164922] 8008  c0481904 00000000 00000000 c03e1248 c03e11a0 00000000 c03de2a8 c03df418

[   67.173080] 8028  00000438 00000780 00000000 00000000 00000018 00000008 00000000 00000000

[   67.181237] 8048  000000ff 000000ff 00000000 00000000 33c11dc0 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.189400] 8068  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002 00000001 00000014 00000000 00000000

[   67.197559] 8088  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.205720] 

[   67.205723] R7: 0xf6288f80:

[   67.209971] 8f80  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa

[   67.218131] 8fa0  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa

[   67.226292] 8fc0  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa

[   67.234449] 8fe0  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa

[   67.242612] 9000  08e57817 0000000f f5419c00 00000000 00000001 00000001 f5419d40 f5b4bc10

[   67.250770] 9020  00000001 0f9a0f9a dead4ead ffffffff ffffffff f6289034 f6289034 00000000

[   67.258932] 9040  00000000 f6289020 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 f6289058 f6289058

[   67.267091] 9060  f6289060 f6289060 f6289068 f6289068 00000000 00000000 00a00000 00870000

[   67.275250] 

[   67.275252] R8: 0xf6287f90:

[   67.279504] 7f90  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa

[   67.287663] 7fb0  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa

[   67.295823] 7fd0  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa

[   67.303982] 7ff0  aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa f6386e00 f612a3a8 c0481904 00000000

[   67.312141] 8010  00000000 c03e1248 c03e11a0 00000000 c03de2a8 c03df418 00000438 00000780

[   67.320303] 8030  00000000 00000000 00000018 00000008 00000000 00000000 000000ff 000000ff

[   67.328461] 8050  00000000 00000000 33c11dc0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.336621] 8070  00000000 00000002 00000001 00000014 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[   67.344782] 

[   67.344784] R9: 0xc03fc5b8:

[   67.349033] c5b8  eb156fa3 ea000016 eb020a43 e2506000 1a000001 e3a04000 ea000011 e5d45000

[   67.357195] c5d8  e3a02000 e3550000 03a05007 13a05008 e1a01005 ebfff2f6 e2504000 0afffff4

[   67.365356] c5f8  e59f302c e3550008 e58d4000 e59f2024 e59f0024 e59f1014 01a02003 e5963004

[   67.373514] c618  eb156f8b e1a00004 e8bd807c c0c9f63f c0a3ba78 c0cdf6f9 c0cc6736 c0c9f660

[   67.381674] c638  e92d41f3 e1a04000 e59f1184 e59f0184 eb156f7f e354000c 059f017c 0a00001e

[   67.389834] c658  e5943044 e5932118 e592506c e3550000 059f0168 0a000018 e5152008 e2458018

[   67.397992] c678  e3520000 059f0158 0a000013 e5937288 e5976048 e59600d4 e3500000 0a000000

[   67.406152] c698  eb15aa29 e2877020 e1a00007 eb15aa26 e5943044 e5d3139c e3510000 0a000009

[   67.414314] Process kworker/0:0 (pid: 4, stack limit = 0xf606e2f0)

[   67.420549] Stack: (0xf606ff48 to 0xf6070000)

[   67.424820] ff40:                   f5422d8c f5422d8c f6021fc0 f5422d8c ce45c900 ce462c00

[   67.433051] ff60: ce45ca18 c01af4a8 f6021fc0 00000001 00000000 f6021fc0 ce45ca18 f606e000

[   67.441141] ff80: c16c5319 ce45c900 ce45ca18 f6021fd0 00000009 c01af858 00000000 f6059edc

[   67.449373] ffa0: f6021fc0 c01af6d4 00000013 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c01b3f34

[   67.457532] ffc0: f6059edc 00000000 f6021fc0 00000000 00000000 dead4ead ffffffff ffffffff

[   67.465691] ffe0: f606ffe0 f606ffe0 f6059edc c01b3eb4 c0106c24 c0106c24 00000000 00000000

[   67.473824] [<c03fc68c>] (check_dsi_ctrl_status+0x54/0x1bc) from [<c01af4a8>] (process_one_work+0x200/0x400)

[   67.483787] [<c01af4a8>] (process_one_work+0x200/0x400) from [<c01af858>] (worker_thread+0x184/0x2a4)

[   67.492922] [<c01af858>] (worker_thread+0x184/0x2a4) from [<c01b3f34>] (kthread+0x80/0x90)

[   67.501215] [<c01b3f34>] (kthread+0x80/0x90) from [<c0106c24>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)

[   67.509510] Code: 059f0158 0a000013 e5937288 e5976048 (e59600d4) 

[   67.517435] ---[ end trace 39b994bb8aed4d14 ]---

[   67.521491] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception

[   67.526423] CPU3: stopping

[   67.529207] [<c010c114>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0x11c) from [<c010af90>] (handle_IPI+0x118/0x200)

[   67.538135] [<c010af90>] (handle_IPI+0x118/0x200) from [<c0100578>] (gic_handle_irq+0x100/0x10c)

[   67.546916] [<c0100578>] (gic_handle_irq+0x100/0x10c) from [<c0969040>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70)

[   67.555190] Exception stack(0xf4c8dd90 to 0xf4c8ddd8)

[   67.560425] dd80:                                     e4ceeda0 00000000 05480548 00000001

[   67.568587] dda0: cdf0e0a8 00000000 e4ceeda0 00000000 ffffffff 0000000c 00000000 00000000

[   67.576544] ddc0: f4c8c000 f4c8ddd8 c0968cf0 c0968cf4 60000013 ffffffff

[   67.583365] [<c0969040>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70) from [<c0968cf4>] (_raw_spin_unlock_irq+0xc/0x34)

[   67.592145] [<c0968cf4>] (_raw_spin_unlock_irq+0xc/0x34) from [<c0220e28>] (delete_from_page_cache+0x40/0x5c)

[   67.602032] [<c0220e28>] (delete_from_page_cache+0x40/0x5c) from [<c022befc>] (truncate_inode_page+0xa4/0xb4)

[   67.611933] [<c022befc>] (truncate_inode_page+0xa4/0xb4) from [<c0234110>] (shmem_truncate_range+0x130/0x3cc)

[   67.621615] [<c0234110>] (shmem_truncate_range+0x130/0x3cc) from [<c023458c>] (shmem_evict_inode+0x98/0x13c)

[   67.631628] [<c023458c>] (shmem_evict_inode+0x98/0x13c) from [<c0270d58>] (evict+0x8c/0x150)

[   67.640047] [<c0270d58>] (evict+0x8c/0x150) from [<c026e46c>] (shrink_dcache_for_umount_subtree+0x108/0x13c)
[   67.649862] [<c026e46c>] (shrink_dcache_for_umount_subtree+0x108/0x13c) from [<c026e7fc>] (shrink_dcache_for_umount+0x3c/0x4c)
[   67.661234] [<c026e7fc>] (shrink_dcache_for_umount+0x3c/0x4c) from [<c025cff0>] (generic_shutdown_super+0x1c/0xbc)
[   67.671554] [<c025cff0>] (generic_shutdown_super+0x1c/0xbc) from [<c025d100>] (kill_anon_super+0xc/0x18)
[   67.681008] [<c025d100>] (kill_anon_super+0xc/0x18) from [<c025d228>] (deactivate_locked_super+0x3c/0x68)
[   67.690562] [<c025d228>] (deactivate_locked_super+0x3c/0x68) from [<c0275424>] (sys_umount+0x318/0x330)
[   67.699750] [<c0275424>] (sys_umount+0x318/0x330) from [<c0106120>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
[   69.718711] wcnss crash shutdown 0
[   69.721174] Rebooting in 5 seconds..
[   74.726167] Going down for restart now
[   74.729760] Calling SCM to disable SPMI PMIC arbiter


7 Corrected bytes, 0 unrecoverable blocks
```

Comment: How long it is .Very vast

Comment: yeah ..i know ..but dont know what to post so that one can analyse.. :(